# What is the logic behind this base conversion function?

Tags: c++

I saw the next function on the internet:

```
std::string hexify(unsigned int n)
{
    std::string res;

    do
    {
        std::cout << n <<std::endl;
        res += "0123456789ABCDEF"[n % 16];
        n >>= 4;
    } while (n);

    return std::string(res.rbegin(), res.rend());
}
```

This function convert the integer to be hexa.
I tried to understand the logic behind this, but without success...

I understand what is base 16 and base 10...
Buy whay this function works?

Comment: Where *exactly* are you lost? What line or what semantic part?

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me - what don't you understand?

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
res += "0123456789ABCDEF"[n % 16];
```

is simply the `char` array `"0123456789ABCDEF"` indexed by the the lower half-byte of `n` added to the end of `std::string res`.

then:

```
n >>= 4;
```

shifts `n` right by a half-byte;

then:

```
} while (n);
```

ends the loop when all the half-bytes in `n` have been consumed.

Finally:

```
return std::string(res.rbegin(), res.rend());
```

returns the backward conversion reversed!

So, for example:

```
hexify(0x56AB9);
```

returns the `std::string`:

```
"56AB9"
```

This could have been simplified with:

```
res = "0123456789ABCDEF"[n % 16] + res;  // instead of res += "0123456789ABCDEF"[n % 16];
```

and then simply:

```
return res;  // instead of return std::string(res.rbegin(), res.rend());
```

Answer (score 1):

`n%16` gets the low 4 bits of `n`. `"0123456789ABCDEF"` is an array that holds those characters. `"0123456789ABCDEF"[n%16]` indexes into the array; the result is the character from the array that corresponds to `n%16`, i.e., the hex value of those 4 bits. `n >>= 4;` shifts the value of `n` left by 4 bits, removing the 4 bits that have already been encoded, so the loop can get the next 4 bits. But this puts the hex characters in reverse order, with the low word at the left and the high word at the right, so the last line creates a new `std::strings object with the computed string reversed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been explained well so far, but I'd like to add somethings in case someone may not known.

First the string "0123456789ABCDEF" it its seeing by the compiler as a const char[17] (including the null character). That means that we can use the bracket operator [] to index it. Then if we had "0123456789ABCDEF"[15] that corresponds to the single character 'F'.

Since we are moding the value n by 16. The value of our index varies from 0 - 15 depending on the last 4 bits of n. N % 16 is just a way to mask n.

Because each character in a hexadecimal value is composed by 4 bits, the loop is moving by n >> 4. The values in binary representation varies from 0000 to 1111 or (0-F).

Another important thing to notice is that because the value n is unsigned the right shift operator will shift the bits (4 bits in this case), and fill the left most values with 0. Because of this we will be able to terminate our loop "while(n)" when n reaches 0.

Adding another fact as suggested, the function is looking at the right most bits, and adding them at the end of the res string every time with the "+=" operator. That is why the result creates a string backwards.
    return std::string(res.rbegin(), res.rend());

Comment: Missed the fact that the string conversion is *backwards* and needs to be reversed.